# macro in excel for replacing exact text in word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to replace 100 test ID in my word document.  I had found the below mentioned macro from this site and used. The problem I am facing is, this logic is not replacing the exact matching value. When I try to change Test ID AUTO_1 to AUTO_A, it is also changing the test ID AUTO_10 to AUTO_A0 and AUTO_11 to AUTO_A1.

```
Sub test1()

    Dim pathh As String
    Dim pathhi As String
    Dim oCell  As Integer
    Dim from_text As String, to_text As String
    Dim WA As Object

    pathh = "C:\1.doc"

Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WA.Documents.Open (pathh)
WA.Visible = True

For oCell = 1 To 100
    from_text = Sheet1.Range("A" + CStr(oCell)).Value
    to_text = Sheet1.Range("B" + CStr(oCell)).Value
    With WA
        .Activate
        With .Selection.Find
          .ClearFormatting
          .Replacement.ClearFormatting

          .Text = from_text
          .Replacement.Text = to_text
          .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: have a look at `lookat` for `selection.find`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the from_text to:

```
from_text = Sheet1.Range("A" + CStr(oCell)).Value & " "
```

You could also loop in reverse so that the larger numbers will get replaced first:

```
For ocell = 100 to 1 Step -1
    ...
Next ocell
```